# potentially refactor code to use chained promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

The following code works fine but it seems like there should be a more concise way to write it.  I have looked for examples of chained promises but haven't found anything close enough to this logic to figure out how to do the conversion from this to the chained approach.  Can it be done?

```
var vm = this;

accountingAppService.getInvoiceTypes().then(function (result) {
    vm.invoiceTypes = result;
}, function (e) {
    onError(e);
});

accountingAppService.getReceivablesTypes().then(function (result) {
    vm.receivablesTypes = result;
}, function (e) {
    onError(e);
});

accountingAppService.getGeneralLedgerAccounts().then(function (result) {
    vm.generalLedgerAccounts = result;
}, function (e) {
    onError(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
var getList = ["invoiceTypes","receivableTypes","generalLedgerAccounts"];

getList.forEach(x => getGeneric(x));

function getGeneric(name) {
    var capName = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
    var getFn = accountingAppService["get"+capName];
    getFn().then(function(result) {
        vm[name] = result;
    }, function (e) {
        onError(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Chaining those calls would cause them to execute on after the other. And from the looks of your code, that doesnt seem to be neccesary. What you can do is group them together.

```
Promise.all([
  accountingAppService.getInvoiceTypes(),
  accountingAppService.getReceivablesTypes(),
  accountingAppService.getGeneralLedgerAccounts()
]).then(function (results) {
 vm.invoiceTypes = results[0];
 vm.receivablesTypes = results[1];
 vm.generalLedgerAccounts [2];
}).catch(onError);
```

Seems like you get rid of some code. You could even use destructuring and async/await to make it look even cleaner.

Comment: just in case author decide to use async/await per each call: it would make them sequential as yBroksky suggested to avoid(and I completely agree with him)

Comment: want I meant was to do `await Promise.all(...)`

Comment: `async`/`await` and ES6 promises don't work with the AngularJS framework because AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc...

Comment: Use `$q.all`. But keep in mind that if *any* of the XHRs fail, no results will be returned. The code in the question will return results for the XHRs that don't fail.